# POST request body not available in Express middleware 'req'

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

I have an odd query that has really stumped me.

I have created this Express middleware:

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var router = express.Router()
router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
router.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(router)

router.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.body)
})

router.post((req, res) => {
  ...
})
```

Whever I try to log the body in the router.post, it logs the correct body. However, when I try to log it in the router.use (as shown above), it only returns an empty object. Any thoughts of how I can get the body in middleware? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only isssue I see according to the official documentation is that you've to set the router to the app after declaring all the middlewares as said in the below attached image,

[image]

which means you code should be changed to

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var router = express.Router()
router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
router.use(bodyParser.json())

router.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.body)
})

router.post((req, res) => {
  ...
})

//setting the router as a middleware after declaring all the routes and middleware functions.
app.use(router)
```

References:

1. [Express Routing](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html)
2. [Express Router API](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#router)

Comment: Hummm. It didn't seem to work, unfortunately.

Comment: Actually, I had something else wrong, but your suggestion actually DID solve that problem! Thank you!